# Upper bound on absolute difference with squares

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, mean-absolute-deviation

I'm looking for an upper bound on $E_X\left[\left\vert X^2-(E[X])^2\right\vert\right]$, where $X$ is a nonnegative random variable,  with known $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$, but unknown higher moments.

A lower bound is $E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$, and I wonder if a there is a constant multiple of this as an upper bound?

Comment: Upper bound in terms of what, exactly?  The absolute value sign is superfluous, because $E[X^2] \ge E[X]^2$ in any event, so you are asking for an upper bound for the variance, given that you know the variance.

Comment: The issue is that the absolute value is a nonlinear function.

Comment: @Whuber - the absolute value sign is not superfluous: for non-constant random variables, there is a positive probability that $X<E[X]$ in which case $X^2 -(E[X])^2<0$

Comment: @Henry Thank you -- I had misread that by distributing expectation over the absolute value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have thought you could say:

$E\big|X^2-(E[X])^2\big| \le E\big|X^2+(E[X])^2\big| =  E\big[X^2\big]+(E[X])^2$

As an example to show it can come close:

- suppose $X=1000$ with probability $\frac1{100}$ and $X=0$ otherwise,
- so $E[X]=10$ and $E[X^2]=10000$,
- we get $E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=9900$ and $E[X^2]+(E[X])^2=10100$
- with $E\big|X^2-(E[X])^2\big|=10098$ closer to the upper bound.

---

As to your question of a constant multiple of the variance, the answer seems to be no.  Adjusting the previous example, suppose $X=1000$ with probability $\frac1{100}$ and $X=999$ otherwise, so $E[X]=999.01$ and $E[X^2]=998020.99$, you have $E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=0.0099$ and $E\big|X^2-(E[X])^2\big|=39.570498$, almost four thousand times as big.  This is not the worst case.

Comment: You would have thought but...? Or do you think it still?

Comment: @RichardHardy It was a quick response giving a bound which was not of the form requested.  I often make mistakes when looking at something new (here I initially persuaded myself $E[X^2]$ was a bound and then found a counterexample), so I used a weaker tense and mood to reflect this.  I still think it correct, but I am happy to leave my original words.

Comment: Thanks, I understand.